# How to configure php version in apache

Tags: php, apache

I have a CentOS running with apache installed. And I performed an upgrade for PHP 5.5 version done below

```
root@localhost [/usr/local/apache/conf]# php -v
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct  1 2015 09:29:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

However, my apache still running on older version. Result from phpinfo

```
PHP Version 5.3.10
System  Linux 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 22 22:00:00 UTC 2015 x86_64
Configure Command   './configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-pdo' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '-...
```

Is there anything I can do to configure the most updated php to apahce ? I have read few other links but seems not working for me

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: I finally sorted out by pointing the module in exact location as follow {
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so }